# Como remover uma variável de $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php

A variável `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` mostra isto

> pesquisar.php?page=6&tipo_animal=Gato

Mas o que eu pretendia era obter

> pesquisar.php?tipo_animal=Gato

Que seria retirar a variável page

O que necessito é trazer todo o link sem a variável `page=` pra poder adicionar na página que esta em um loop.

Comment: Não entendi o porque do voto de duplicada ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` traz a url inteira, incluindo a query string, se concactenar ele vai duplicar os `pag=` e vai haver casos que a url vai ficar assim `.php&pag=`.

Faça assim:

```
<?php
    //Pega a URL da página atual .php
    $fullUrl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    //Se não tiver _GET então usa o ?
    $signConcat = '?';

    //Verifica se tem variaveis _GET
    if (empty($_GET) === false) {
         //Copia variáveis
         $gets = $_GET;

         //Verifica se existe 'page' e remove ela
         if (isset($gets['page'])) {
              unset($gets['page']);
         }

         //Se tiver qualquer _GET adiciona o & no prefixo
         $signConcat = '&amp;';

         //Adiciona ao $fullUrl o $gets "formatado"
         $fullUrl .= '?' . http_build_query($gets, '', '&amp;');
    }
?>
```

E chame no seu loop assim:

```
<a href="' . $fullUrl . $signConcat . 'page=' .$i. '">'.$i. '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
```

Comment: Mas isso vai trazer o link sem a variavel page ?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes sim o `unset($gets['page']);` remove o `page=` ;)

Comment: Resolveu certinho obrigado :$

Comment: Perfeito funcionou :D

Comment: dá para remover o " Essa pergunta já existe e foi respondida aqui:
Como executar uma paginação com PDO?" esta pergunta é diferente

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes é o cache do site, leva algumas horas pra sumir, mas não tem problema aparecer linkado, uma pergunta leva a outra, na outra pergunta as pessoas verão a sua ou seja a sua pergunta esta ótima e ajudará quem encontrar aquela outra pergunta. É tipo os "videos relacionados do youtube" só que pra perguntas :) - Não se preocupe não vai duplicar mais, eu já removi meu voto e ninguem mais vai votar porque esta bem diferente... E se alguém duplicar e vou e removo a duplicata pra voltar ao normal. Pode ficar tranquilo.

Comment: Ok obrigado ^_^